# Connected graph as connected space

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be locally finite graph. By $|G|$, we mean the Freudenthal compactification of the 1-complex $G$, see chapter 8 of "Graph Theory" by Diestel. It is followed from Lemma 8.5.4 of Diestel's book:
Every connected standard subspace of $|G|$ is arc-connected. So if $|G|$ is a connected space, then $|G|$ is an arc-connected space, and so $G$ is connected as graph.

Now, my question is:
Assume that $G$ is connected as graph. Is $|G|$ is a connected space?

It is true in the finite case. But I am not sure about the locally finite case.

Comment: What part of the proof for the finite case goes wrong in the locally finite case?  I don't have the book to check the definitions, but since in a connected graph any two vertices are joined by a path of finite length, it seems to me that you should only have to look at finitely many vertices at a time.

Comment: @NateEldredge infnite graphs have ends, so closed infinite subset of vertices may have end.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand.  Maybe I am naive, but the only definition of "connected graph" I know is that for every pair of vertices $a,b$, there is a finite list of vertices $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ such that $x_0 = a$, $x_n = b$, and $x_i \sim x_{i+1}$.  Is there a different definition which you are using?

Comment: Any compactification of a connected space is connected.

Comment: The closure of any connected set is connected.

Comment: @EricWofsey No I mean by connected is a graphical connectedness i.e there is a path between every vertex.

Comment: @NateEldredge in the finite case, the closure of any subset of vertices is itself, but here the closure of any subset of vertices may have ends. Is it clear?